# The probability of coming out ahead in a european roulette

Tags: probability

Suppose I've bring 500 dollar to a roulette game, and spend 5$ every spin placing on a corner(4/37 winning), what's my chance to coming out ahead after 89 spins? what about 91 spins?

Comment: If you're asking whether you should gamble: no.

Comment: @user140943 That's clearly not the question.

Comment: @user140943 It's just a question base on hypothesis but still thanks for the caring ;)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you never specified when you stopped playing, and if you keep playing until you cant (you run out of money) then you have a 100% chance of losing your money if you keep playing indefinitely. Probably not the answer you are looking for, but the mathematically correct one to your question.

Comment: This isn't a real life situation but only a math question base on hypothesis, thanks for answering any way ;)

Comment: Im saying that in a mathematical sense, you asked what the odds are of coming out ahead, and if you never declare a stop to playing, you never end up ahead. My answer is both logically and mathematically sound as an answer to your posted question, even if it is useless.

Comment: now that i see you edited your problem to 91 and 89 spins, my answer is now inadequate

Answer (score 0):

On any bet, you lose $5$ dollars with probability $\frac{33}{37}$, and win $40$ dollars with probability $\frac{4}{37}$. Your $\$500$ is enough to make sure that you don't get wiped out.

After $90$ plays, we would come out "even" if we had $10$ wins and $80$ losses. So with $89$ plays we come out ahead if we have $10$ or more wins. Let the probability of this be $p$. It is easier to calculate first the probability $1-p$ of the *complementary event* that we get $9$ or fewer wins. The probability of $k$ wins is 
$$\binom{89}{k}\left(\frac{4}{37}\right)^k \left(\frac{33}{37}\right)^{89-k}.$$
Thus 
$$1-p=\sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{89}{k}\left(\frac{4}{37}\right)^k\left(\frac{33}{37}\right)^{89-k}.$$
It is feasible but not pleasant to evaluate $1-p$ by hand. Wolfram Alpha will compute the above sum easily. But if we use Alpha, we might as well not think, and just calculate the sum from $10$ to $89$.